# How to disable opening of dropdown in select box in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile for showing drop-down for select box.

```
<select id="category_type" multiple="multiple" class="category" tabindex="-1" placeholder="Category">
<option></option>
.
.
</select>
```

In some condition I need to restrict opening of the drop-down of select box when clicked.

I tried with

```
jQuery("#category_type").bind( "change", function(e) {
   jQuery.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.hidePlaceholderMenuItems = false;
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

But not effective.
How can it be possible?.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by restrict opening?

Comment: @Omar thank you for your response.  I actually mean to disable or block the option list when clicking on the select menu. I dnt need to show the option list populated when clicking in select box but the style and all is needed for me.

Comment: Disable it http://stackoverflow.com/a/19682317/1771795

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: Here is the working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/6esm7qxm/16/)

HTML Part:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <button id="disable_select">Disable</button>
    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS Part:

```
$("#disable_select").click(function() {
    $("#select-choice-1").attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

Right now I have added a button to disable the dropdown on click of that button, you can add your condition to disable it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. this attribute I already used but not effective

Comment: @VishnuPrasad But perfectly working on my side. What is the problem ??

Comment: I fount a method to disable the select box in html itself.. and when needed enables it.. its the current activity i made.But if I get opening event of jQuery Moblie then problem can be fixed